# Help recognize a special matrix

Tags: matrices

Can anyone recognize the following matrix or at least the implied logic of the $\dots$ entries. It seems clear the matrix is symmetrical and that element $(1,n) = \frac{1}{n}$ and I guess element $(1,2) = \frac{1}{2}$ but what is element $(2,n)$ or $(n-1,n-1)$?

[image: Matrix]

Why ask? I accepted a work assignment (without looking well enough over the material) where I have to write a program the builds the following matrix - I suspect it relates to statistics/probability application.

Comment: I don't think it is a serious question. Tell your dad it's a lost cause and keep going with those other businesses of yours, Chopin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix has coefficients $a_{ij}=\frac{1}{i+j-1}$, which is a special case of a [Cauchy matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix).

Comment: One can go a step further: It's a [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix).

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is written at the Wikipedia link in line $5$ - but your link is much nicer!